# Loadster capturing rule found no matches for variable __RequestVerificationToken

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, token, stress-testing

I'm trying to stress test my application with Loadster but every single Post method throw warning/error  __RequestVerificationToken is empty or undefined as in the Get method it has the warning about capturing rule found no matches for variable __RequestVerificationToken.

This is the default way to capture in the Get method

[image]

I tried these two capture ways as well to capture

```
<input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="
```

and

```
<input name="__RequestVerificationToken" value="
```

as you can see here

[image]

but still having the same warnings.

by the way, I do have this key in the HTML file.

[image]
Any clue?

Answer (score 0):

After you record a script, Loadster automatically adds [capturing rules](https://loadster.app/documentation/manual/capturing-rules/) for some server-generated tokens, including `__RequestVerificationToken`, when it sees them regurgitated from the client to the server in a subsequent request. It does this by backtracking the graph of recorded requests/responses until it finds where they originated.

When Loadster's recorder finds a match for one of these tokens, it will create a capturer on the *originating* step (where the value was first seen in a response) and a parameterized variable in the *subsequent* step(s) where the value is returned to the server.

The important thing to keep in mind is that the capturing rule is based solely on information available at the time of recording. If something is different at playback, the capturer may fail to find a value, and you'll get this error.

The most likely explanation is that an earlier step in your script failed to produce the expected state, and now the server isn't actually returning the page with the `__RequestVerificationToken`. For example, an earlier login in your script may have failed, and now when you request the form you're getting some kind of error page instead of the form you expected.

You can confirm this in Loadster using the **Requests** tab at the bottom of the script editor. After playing a script, a tree of all requests and responses appears in this section, and you can drill down to see the exact response that your server returned. Most likely you won't see a `__RequestVerificationToken` in this response (that's why capturing failed) but you will probably see something else that explains it. You may also need to backtrack in the tree to an earlier request/response to see where it went off the rails.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the place Loadster attached the "Capture" from the recording was not correct. After recording, it attached the "Capture" rule to the *POST* request that resulted from the form submission. The token to be captured though was actually generated by the preceding GET request.

To correct this, I simply moved (retyped) the `Capture csrfmiddlewaretoken from HTML input csrfmiddlewaretoken` from the POST request to the preceding GET and it worked.

---

This isn't actually the case for the OP, but search results for this error are slim, so this seemed like a good place to put this.